Export data from OpenSearch in private VPC
I am currently working on exporting data from Opensearch index. I am using this code for now.
# imports
import logging
from typing import Dict, List, Set, Tuple, Union
from opensearchpy import OpenSearch, RequestsHttpConnection

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format="%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s")


class OpenSearchEmbeddings:

    def __init__(self, auth: Tuple[str, str], host: str, index_name: str) -> None:
        """
        The class provides methods to perform various operations on the OpenSearch domain,
        such as indexing documents,
        and searching for similar documents. The attributes are as follows :

        auth: The authentication credentials to connect to the OpenSearch server.
        Here we use the master user credentials
        host: The endpoint url of the OpenSearch domain.
        index_name: The name of the index in the OpenSearch server.
        client: An instance of the OpenSearch client for interacting with the
        OpenSearch server. It is initialized with the provided parameters.
        """

        self.host = host
        self.index_name = index_name
        self.auth = auth
        self.client = OpenSearch(
            hosts=[{"host": host, "port": 443}],
            http_auth=auth,
            use_ssl=True,
            verify_certs=True,
            connection_class=RequestsHttpConnection,
            pool_maxsize=20,
        )

    def delete_current_index(self) -> None:
        """
        Method of the `OpenSearchEmbeddings` class that is used to delete the
        current index from the OpenSearch server.
        """

        self.client.indices.delete(index=self.index_name)

        logger.info("Index deleted successfully.")

    def delete_index(self, index_name: str) -> None:
        """
        Method of the `OpenSearchEmbeddings` class that is used to delete an
        index from the OpenSearch server.
        The 'index_name' can ( and is supposed to) be different from self.index_name.
        If the same, use function 'delete_current_index'
        """

        self.client.indices.delete(index=index_name)

        logger.info("Index deleted successfully.")

    def list_indices(self) -> List[str]:
        """
        Methods listing all the indices in the Opensearch domain
        """

        response = self.client.indices.get_alias().keys()
        indices = list(response)

        return indices

    def count_documents(self) -> int:
        """
        Methods returns the list of documents in the index
        """

        response = self.client.search(index=self.index_name, body={"query": {"match_all": {}}})
        documents = response["hits"]["total"]["value"]
        logging.info(f"Number of documents in index: {documents}")

        return documents

    def get_elements(self) -> Dict:
        """
        get the text, embedding, and metadata fields of all documents in the Opensearch index.
        """
        try:
            response = self.client.search(index=self.index_name, body={"query": {"match_all": {}}})
            return response["hits"]["hits"]

        except Exception as e:
            logging.exception("Error: ", str(e))
            raise e

However when I use the get_elements functions it only gives me 10 rows of data while I wan to have all data.
Did anyone already worked on this ? Any help would be appreciated.
Here is a related question that was asked on stackoverflow. I am using the endpoint method.
Thank you for your help.
I tried the get_elements function :
opensearch_client = OpenSearchEmbeddings(auth, host, index_name)
elements = opensearch_client.get_elements()
However it does not give the output expected.

Include the code where you call the get_elements function and handle the response.
